# Date not found in pandas table but seen with iloc

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Consider the following table taken (Partly shown below).

| NAV value | NAV date |
| --- | --- |
| 9.85 | 22-Sep-2017 |
| 9.76 | 23-Sep-2017 |

These are the two columns present. If the NAV date is a weekend or holiday then there is no entry for it.

The date at a 1 year gap was found as

```
end_date = start_date + pd.to_timedelta(365,unit='D')
```

for the entry 22-Sep-2017 the value of end_date was
Timestamp('2018-09-22 00:00:00')

Since this was a weekend this was not present in the NAV date column as seen below

```
end_date in df['NAV date']
# Output False
```

So I added 2 days to the start date

```
new_end_date = end_date + pd.to_timedelta(2,unit='D')
#value Timestamp('2018-09-24 00:00:00')
new_end_date in df['NAV date']
#Output False
```

However I expected this date 24-Sep-2018 to be present in the table and I feel it is there

```
df.iloc[247]
#Ouput
Net Asset Value                 11.2527
Repurchase Price                    NaN
Sale Price                          NaN
NAV date            2018-09-24 00:00:00
diff                    3 days 00:00:00
Name: 247, dtype: object
# dtpyes of table
Net Asset Value             float64
Repurchase Price             object
Sale Price                   object
NAV date             datetime64[ns]
diff                timedelta64[ns]
dtype: object
```

Can anyone tell me why *new_end_date in df['NAV date']* failed when I can see it in the table using iloc?
I am not sure if I am missing something

Comment: check if `df.iloc[247]['Nav date'] == new_end_date`

Comment: @AsishM. df.iloc[247]['NAV date'] == new_end_date gives True but new_end_date in df['NAV date'] seems to be giving false